# Show that the set $\{x\in E: \text{$f_n(x)$ does not converge to $f(x)$}\}$ is measurable

Tags: measure-theory

**Definition**. Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space and $E\in\mathcal{M}$. Let $f:X\to\Bbb R$ and $f_n:X\to\Bbb R$ be measurable functions for all $n\in \Bbb R$. We say that $f_n$ converges to $f$ pointwise almost everywhere provided $\mu(\{x\in E: \text{$f(x)$ does  not converge to $f(x)$}\})=0.$

**Question**. I think we have
\begin{align}
\{x\in E: \text{$f(x)$ does  not converge to $f(x)$}\} &=\{x\in E: \neg (\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)=f(x)) \} \\&=\{x\in E: \text{$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$ does not exist}\}\sqcup\{x\in E: \lim_{n\to\infty}|f_n(x)-f(x)|>0\}.
\end{align}

So, how can we show that these sets are measurable? Thanks!

Comment: The set where the sequence $f_n$ converges is $C=\bigcap_n\bigcup_m\bigcap_{k\geq m}\bigcap_{\ell\geq m}\{|f_k(x)-f_\ell(x)|<\tfrac1n\}$, which is formed by countable unions and intersections of measurable sets. Its complement is therefore also measurable.